# batch not_if guard says "action run" rather than "skipped"

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I have a PS script in recipe that causes chef-run to fail if a certain Security Policy is enabled (basically [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/04/18/task-scheduler-error-a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist/) problem).

So I have added a not_if guard

```
  powershell_script 'scheduled-tasks' do
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    cwd 'C:\Temp'
    code <<-EOH
      schtasks.exe /create ...
      schtasks.exe /create ...
    EOH
    not_if "(get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Lsa').DisableDomainCreds -eq '1'"
  end
```

I am using Test-Kitchin, VirtualBox and Windows VMs. Running the powershell command 'getitemproperty...' returns True meaning it is Enabled and thus I do not want the script run and expect Chef to say 'skipped due to not_if'.

However, in the terminal output it says "action run".

The chef run doesn't fail so the script cannot have run, but why does it not say "skipped"?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using double quotes for your not_if statement. Try using curly braces or single quotes instead. Beware of the Powershell logical operator that is using single quotes likewise:

```
not_if '(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Lsa).DisableDomainCreds -eq "1"'
```